# Sveltekit Display API Data

Tags: typescript, rest, svelte, sveltekit

I want to display the data from an API into a table group. However, I am having trouble coming up with a logic to displaying the data into a table by group.

For example tables like theses (images).

[image: Group Blue Table]
[image: Group Red Table]

The API response

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "position": 1,
            "points": 0,
            "status": "",
            "player": {
                "id": 18,
                "gender": "male",
                "name": "Andrew",
                "image": "",
                "dob": "",
                "nationality": "",
                "placeholder": false
            },
            "phase": {
                "id": 200,
                "name": "First Round",
                "finished": false,
                "starting": "",
                "ending": "",
                "groups": [
                    {
                        "id": 100,
                        "phaseId": 300,
                        "name": "Group Blue",
                        "starting": "2018-11-16",
                        "ending": "2020-06-11",
                        "finished": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 101,
                        "phaseId": 301,
                        "name": "Group Red",
                        "starting": "2018-11-16",
                        "ending": "2020-06-11",
                        "finished": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 102,
                        "phaseId": 302,
                        "name": "Group Green",
                        "starting": "2018-11-16",
                        "ending": "2020-06-11",
                        "finished": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 103,
                        "phaseId": 303,
                        "name": "Group Yellow",
                        "starting": "2018-11-16",
                        "ending": "2020-06-11",
                        "finished": "false"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "group": {
                "id": 100,
                "phaseId": 300,
                "name": "Group Blue",
                "starting": "2018-11-16",
                "ending": "2020-06-11",
                "finished": "false"
            },
            "details": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "value": 0,
                    "name": "Geography"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "value": 0,
                    "name": "Mathematics"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "value": 0,
                    "name": "Arts"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 20,
            "position": 1,
            "points": 0,
            "status": "",
            "player": {
                "id": 30,
                "gender": "male",
                "name": "Gerry",
                "image": "",
                "dob": "",
                "nationality": "",
                "placeholder": false
            },
            "phase": {
                "id": 200,
                "name": "First Round",
                "finished": false,
                "starting": "",
                "ending": "",
                "groups": [
                    {
                        "id": 100,
                        "phaseId": 300,
                        "name": "Group Blue",
                        "starting": "2018-11-16",
                        "ending": "2020-06-11",
                        "finished": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 101,
                        "phaseId": 301,
                        "name": "Group Red",
                        "starting": "2018-11-16",
                        "ending": "2020-06-11",
                        "finished": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 102,
                        "phaseId": 302,
                        "name": "Group Green",
                        "starting": "2018-11-16",
                        "ending": "2020-06-11",
                        "finished": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 103,
                        "phaseId": 303,
                        "name": "Group Yellow",
                        "starting": "2018-11-16",
                        "ending": "2020-06-11",
                        "finished": "false"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "group": {
                "id": 101,
                "phaseId": 300,
                "name": "Group Red",
                "starting": "2018-11-16",
                "ending": "2020-06-11",
                "finished": "false"
            },
            "details": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "value": 0,
                    "name": "Geography"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "value": 0,
                    "name": "Mathematics"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "value": 0,
                    "name": "Arts"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 30,
            "position": 1,
            "points": 0,
            "status": "",
            "player": {
                "id": 56,
                "gender": "male",
                "name": "David",
                "image": "",
                "dob": "",
                "nationality": "",
                "placeholder": false
            },
            "phase": {
                "id": 200,
                "name": "First Round",
                "finished": false,
                "starting": "",
                "ending": "",
                "groups": [
                    {
                        "id": 100,
                        "phaseId": 300,
                        "name": "Group Blue",
                        "starting": "2018-11-16",
                        "ending": "2020-06-11",
                        "finished": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 101,
                        "phaseId": 301,
                        "name": "Group Red",
                        "starting": "2018-11-16",
                        "ending": "2020-06-11",
                        "finished": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 102,
                        "phaseId": 302,
                        "name": "Group Green",
                        "starting": "2018-11-16",
                        "ending": "2020-06-11",
                        "finished": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 103,
                        "phaseId": 303,
                        "name": "Group Yellow",
                        "starting": "2018-11-16",
                        "ending": "2020-06-11",
                        "finished": "false"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "group": {
                "id": 100,
                "phaseId": 300,
                "name": "Group Blue",
                "starting": "2018-11-16",
                "ending": "2020-06-11",
                "finished": "false"
            },
            "details": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "value": 0,
                    "name": "Geography"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "value": 0,
                    "name": "Mathematics"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "value": 0,
                    "name": "Arts"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 40,
            "position": 2,
            "points": 0,
            "status": "",
            "player": {
                "id": 60,
                "gender": "female",
                "name": "Jane",
                "image": "",
                "dob": "",
                "nationality": "",
                "placeholder": false
            },
            "phase": {
                "id": 200,
                "name": "First Round",
                "finished": false,
                "starting": "",
                "ending": "",
                "groups": [
                    {
                        "id": 100,
                        "phaseId": 300,
                        "name": "Group Blue",
                        "starting": "2018-11-16",
                        "ending": "2020-06-11",
                        "finished": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 101,
                        "phaseId": 301,
                        "name": "Group Red",
                        "starting": "2018-11-16",
                        "ending": "2020-06-11",
                        "finished": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 102,
                        "phaseId": 302,
                        "name": "Group Green",
                        "starting": "2018-11-16",
                        "ending": "2020-06-11",
                        "finished": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 103,
                        "phaseId": 303,
                        "name": "Group Yellow",
                        "starting": "2018-11-16",
                        "ending": "2020-06-11",
                        "finished": "false"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "group": {
                "id": 101,
                "phaseId": 300,
                "name": "Group Red",
                "starting": "2018-11-16",
                "ending": "2020-06-11",
                "finished": "false"
            },
            "details": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "value": 0,
                    "name": "Geography"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "value": 0,
                    "name": "Mathematics"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "value": 0,
                    "name": "Arts"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This the sveltekit code

+Page.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
    import type { PageData } from './$types';
    export let data: PageData;

    $: classes = data?.classes;
    
</script>

<h1>Class Scores</h1>


<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Pos.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Geography</th>
        <th>Mathematics</th>
        <th>Art</th>
      </tr>
</table>

<!-- <ul>
    {#each classes as points}
    <li>{points}</li>
    {/each}
</ul> -->
```

+Page.ts

```js
import type { PageLoad } from "./$types";

export const load = (async ({ fetch }) => {
   

    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/data`)

    const classes = await response.json();
    console.log(classes);

    return {
        classes
    }

}) satisfies PageLoad
```

Any help to lead me into the right direction, would be helpful.

Comment: You would need to 'postprocess' your data, either in the load function or in the script, iterate over the array and fill new arrays with the people, at the same time strip any data that is not relevant from your objects like gender, nationality etc...
Personally I would use a mix: strip irrelevant parts in the load, transform in the script tag just in case you want to be able to be flexible in the way the data is grouped or sorted.

Comment: Thanks @StephaneVanraes , for leading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the table (sort of), just CSS now. Not the best way, but it did the trick.

As mention by @Stephane, I did 'postprocess' the data where I grouped the response from the API by the group name.

+Page.ts

```
import type { PageLoad } from "./$types";

export const load = (async ({ fetch }) => {
   

    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/data`)

    const classes = await response.json();

    let result = classes.reduce(function (r:any,a:any) {
        r[a.group.name] = r[a.group.name] || [];
        r[a.group.name].push(a);
        return r
      }, Object.create(null));

      console.log(result);
    return {
        result
    }

}) satisfies PageLoad
```

+Page.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
    import type { PageData } from './$types';
    export let data: PageData;

    $: classes = data?.result;
</script>

<h1>Class Scores</h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{classes['Group Blue'][0].group.name}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Pos.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Geography</th>
        <th>Mathematics</th>
        <th>Art</th>
        <th>Total Pts</th>
    </tr>
    {#each classes['Group Blue'] as { position, points, player, details }}
        <tr>
            <td>{position}</td>
            <td>{player.name}</td>
            <td>{details[0].value}</td>
            <td>{details[1].value}</td>
            <td>{details[2].value}</td>
            <td>{points}</td>
        </tr>
    {/each}
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{classes['Group Blue'][0].group.name}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Pos.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Geography</th>
        <th>Mathematics</th>
        <th>Art</th>
        <th>Total Pts</th>
    </tr>
    {#each classes['Group Red'] as { position, points, player, details }}
        <tr>
            <td>{position}</td>
            <td>{player.name}</td>
            <td>{details[0].value}</td>
            <td>{details[1].value}</td>
            <td>{details[2].value}</td>
            <td>{points}</td>
        </tr>
    {/each}
</table>
```

Result

[image]